# Process.Start() Google and select account

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I'm trying to open the google browser, but whenever I open google I'm requierd to choose an acount.

How can I make the app to open google and choose an acount??

the code I'm using:

```
string[] sites = { "google.com", "youtube.com", "github.com" };

foreach(string site in sites)
{
   string url = "http://www." + sites;
   Process.Start("chrome.exe",url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a new argument to include the profile which is `--profile-directory="profileName"`

```
string profileName = "PROFILENAME"; // Replace PROFILENAME with the desired profile name

//Note below.  Changed to use https.  Typo in your code, should be "site" not "sites"
string url = "https://www." + site;

string argument = $"\"{url}\" --profile-directory=\"{profileName}\"";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("chrome.exe");
psi.Arguments = argument;
Process.Start(psi);
```